# Avisoft-RECORDER "GetOverlappedResult" error in a Virtualbox guest Windows

Tags: windows-7, windows-8.1, virtualbox, usb-2

Using Avisoft-RECORDER USGH in a guest Windows 7 and Windows 8.1, under Virtualbox 5.1.6-dfsg-2 of an Ubuntu 16.10 host, after a second or two of recording, I am getting the following error:

title:

```
Avisoft-RECORDER USGH Recording / USB Interface Error
```

Body:

```
GetOverlappedResult(): bytes transferred : 0, error code: e0000b00.
```

the recording stops completely and I am left to restart it manually.

Avisoft provides a crude workaround - checking the `Ignore GetOverlappedResult error` option in their RECORDER program.
After checking this option, whenever the GetOverlappedResult arises, the recording is stopped and restarted automatically.

Will all audio data still be recorded or will there be a gap for each GetOverlappedResult error?

Is there a way of completely eliminating this error?

the device I am using has the label:

```
Avisoft Bioacoustics
UtraSoundGate 116Hme
Serial No.: 116Hm / 12
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use a computer with a native Windows version installed on it.

Running the software under Virtualbox can indeed cause such USB transfer errors, which are probably caused the slow USB implementation of your system. So, it is an issue of the Virtualbox/Ubuntu system rather than the RECORDER USGH software.

Regards,
Raimund